# Calculate the angle between 2 segments in 3D space with plain python

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

I have two segments in a 3D space defined by the coordinates of their starting and ending points.

I need to calculate the angle between these two segments in python without numpy or other fancy libs.

I wrote the following code, which seems correct to me:

```
def CalcAngle(beg1, end1, beg2, end2):

  vect1 = [None, None, None]
  vect2 = [None, None, None]

  for cc in range(3):
    vect1[cc] = end1[cc] - beg1[cc]
    vect2[cc] = end2[cc] - beg2[cc]

  length1 = math.sqrt(vect1[0]**2+vect1[1]**2+vect1[2]**2)
  length2 = math.sqrt(vect2[0]**2+vect2[1]**2+vect2[2]**2)

  dotProd = 0.0
  for cc in range(3):
    dotProd += (vect1[cc] * vect2[cc])

  angleRad = math.acos( dotProd / (length1 * length2) )
  angleDeg = math.degrees(angleRad)

  return angleRad, angleDeg

# 1st segment
beg1 = [47.737, 31.8, 21.762]
end1 = [43.55, 38.956, 42.209]

# 2nd segment 
beg2 = [35.993, 18.033, 56.988]
end2 = [31.497, 18.783, 68.881]

angleRad, angleDeg = CalcAngle(beg1, end1, beg2, end2)

# angleRad is 0.312973304876
# angleDeg is 17.9320494697
```

Am I missing something here?
Is there any situation where my code will not work ?

Thank you.

Comment: There might be some extreme cases where due to floating point rounding errors the argument of `acos` could be bigger than `1`. You also can face division by zero. You may put a `try` `except` or `if` condition. The initializing of the `vec`s is not necessary.

Comment: Hi @mikuszefski, thank you for your reply. I will add some if conditions.

Comment: @clusterman beg1 coordinates are [X,Y,Z]?

Comment: Hi @ZarakiKenpachi, yes beg1, end1, beg2 and end2 coordinates are x, y, z.

Comment: @clusterman i think the calculation are ok. I get the same result. On the plotted graph the angle seems by around 20 degree

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi thank you for your check

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. If you do so, please, remove this copy of the question.